# Как сделать так, чтобы высота контейнера была фиксированной, но уменьшалась, если не помещается в окно браузера?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, height

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
        .container {
            display: flex;
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Hello, world!</div>
    <div>Good night, world!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать vh img { max-height:95vh; }
[Источник](https://habr.com/ru/post/126863/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.class { height: 100vh; max-height: 300px; }
```